# Extraño comportamiento PWA

Tags: pwa, framework7

Hace 8 meses atrás terminé de desarrollar y estuve trabajando con mi 1er. PWA (FrameWork 7) y todo marchaba muy bien, pero ahora en determinados modelos de dispositivos (Pixel 3a) uno de ellos) existe un coportamiento extraño en el uso de la PWA, les explico...

Cuando se despliega el "home" en el bottom Toolbar existen dos links(Inicio y Configuración), pero al yo tocar la pantalla del dispositivo se muestran los botones "generales" del Sistema Android y los dos links desaparecen, esto no lo hacia anteriormente, incluso para navegar por el "home" me cuestra trabajo hacer scroll por el mismo problema,ignoro si una actualización del sistema Android trajo este "detalle"

[image: Pantalla home]
[image: Inmediatamente al tocar la pantalla se muestra los botones del SO Android]

Este es mi manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Mi Score",
    "short_name": "Mi Score",
    "description": "Aplicación Móvil para el seguimiento de un determinado torneo",
    "background_color": "#040404",
    "theme_color": "#040404",
    "display": "fullscreen",
    "orientation": "any",
    "start_url": "/index.html",
    "scope": "./",
    "lang": "es-MX",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_1024.png",
        "sizes": "1024x1024",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "any"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_128.png",
        "sizes": "128x128",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_64.png",
        "sizes": "64x64",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_32.png",
        "sizes": "32x32",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      },
      {
        "src": "./img/icon_16.png",
        "sizes": "16x16",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Listo, encontré el problema... es un bug de Chrome en la nueva versión

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68856575/android-os-nav-and-status-bars-toggling-in-and-out-on-fullscreen-pwa

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).